# Formatting regex output in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I format output from regex or return regex output in specific format.

For example:
I have a program **test_program:5.4.3.2.11111**

and I want to obtain only this value: **5.4.3.2.11111**

If I use this function:

```py
import re

get_number = "test_program:5.4.3.2.11111"
number = re.findall('\d+', get_number)
```

the output is:

```
['5', '4', '3', '2', '11111']
```

but I cannot pass it to another variable due to incorrect formatting.

I've use something like this:

```py
import re

get_number = re.compile(r'\d.\d.\d.d.\d\d\d\d\d')
number = get_number.search('test_program:5.4.3.2.11111')
print(number.group())
```

and the output is in the correct format but if any number changes ex **5** will change to **10** or **11111** will change to **1111112**, this will not work correctly.

Is there any better solution to obtain number from string in proper format that will not be vurnable to changes?

Comment: Read up on [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/7414759)

Comment: `"test_program:5.4.3.2.11111".split(":")[1]` gives `"5.4.3.2.11111"`

Comment: `".".join(['5', '4', '3', '2', '11111'])` gives `"5.4.3.2.11111"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex to obtain the desired result

```
import re

get_number = "test_program:5.4.3.2.11111"
number = re.findall('[\d.]+', get_number)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use repeaters for the `\d` values so they match 1 or more times (instead of exactly one time):

```
import re


get_number = re.compile(r'\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+')
number = get_number.search('test_program:15.4.3.2.111112')
print(number.group())

>>> 15.4.3.2.111112
```